# How to sort month in a table when retrieving using the sql query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select-query

I have a query which gets month name from a table. But this **column isn't a datetime data type**, It's a v**archar column**. How can I sort it according to the month name in ascending order?
This is the output I get at the moment.

> August
>   November
>   October
>   September

This is my query

```
select distinct(payemnt_month) as month from payement_details
```

Comment: do you have any other corresponding date or datetime column in the table ?

Comment: No, I dont have any other column with datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below one i have appended your month with day and year. Then i am extracting month number

```
select * from payment_details order by DATEPART(MM,payemnt_month+'01'+'00')
```

**Update** 
If possible update your query like below.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT month,
                Datepart(MM, payemnt_month+ '01' + '00') MONTHNO
FROM   payment_details )A
ORDER  BY MONTHNO
```

Or Like below if you don't have any issue to keep month no

```
   SELECT DISTINCT month,
                        Datepart(MM, payemnt_month+ '01' + '00') MONTHNO
        FROM   payment_details
order by month,Datepart(MM, payemnt_month+ '01' + '00')
```

Comment: I tried to change the query accoring to mine. But it gives me the following error.     Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: What and all columns you have specified after distinct? Can you post your entire query?

Comment: This is the entire query

Comment: @Mike Updated post check now.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN payment_month='August' THEN 8
              WHEN payment_month='November' THEN 11
              WHEN payment_month='October' THEN 10
              WHEN payment_month='September' THEN 9 END
```

Frame your `ORDER BY` clause as above and add remaining months into it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Just put order by clause as:

```
select distinct(payemnt_month) as month from payement_details order by payemnt_month
```